# Algorithm of getting free IP address

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, optimization, yii2

I use yii2. And I need to find IP which is not used (is not in database) by method getFreeIPAddress. I have class like this:

```
class Radreply extends ActiveRecord {

   const ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS = 'Framed-IP-Address';

   const IP_ADDRESS_MAX = '10.255.255.255';  // max value for IP 
   const IP_ADDRESS_MIN = '10.0.0.11';       // min value for IP

   public function getIntegerIP(){  // converts IP from string to integer format
       return ip2long($this->value);
   }

   public static function getFreeIPAddress(){
        $records = self::findAll(['attribute'=>self::ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS]); // get all record which contain IP address
        $existIPs = ArrayHelper::getColumn($records,'integerIP'); // get array of IP which is converted to integer by method getIntegerIP

        for ($integerIP = ip2long(self::IP_ADDRESS_MIN); $integerIP<=ip2long(self::IP_ADDRESS_MAX); $integerIP++){
        // increasing one by one IP address in integer format from value IP_ADDRESS_MIN to value IP_ADDRESS_MAX

            if (!in_array($integerIP, $existIPs)){
                $stringIP = long2ip($integerIP);
                $arrayDigits = explode('.', $stringIP);
                $lastDigit = array_pop($arrayDigits);

                if ($lastDigit!='0'){ // check if last digit of IP is not 0
                    return $stringIP;
                }

            }

        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Method getFreeIPAddress works find, but in db there are a lot of records with IP and increasing one by one IP and checking if this IP exist in db is very long way. How I can optimize this algorithm? Is there faster way to get unused IP?

Comment: ummmm you could make a table of all available IP addresses, and then right join against your other table to get a list of free IP addresses

Comment: @cmorrissey thanks good idea. But will be problem if I want to change the range of available IP address, I will need to create new table each time. Also this table will be very big: min - 10.0.0.11', max - '10.255.255.255' (16 777 204 records)

Comment: okay I have a new idea for you ... count the number of rows in your database between a range of IP addresses to see if there is an available IP Address if not go to the next range, and you can do this recursively narrowing your range.  This is a very rudimentary search function but it should speed up your search exponentially.

Comment: @cmorrissey I don't understand actually what do you mean. can you describe in details? But anyway thanks, counting it is good idea, I think counting is the key of optimization for this algorithm

Comment: Do as @cmorrissey suggests and create a table of available IP addresses. So what if it's big, with 16 million rows it will still be 16 megabytes + whatever overhead your SQL db has. Besides, you don't need to create a new table if you need to add more addresses to your pool, you just insert more rows into that table! Also, if you're using MySQL, you might want to convert to and from integers in your queries using `INET_ATON()` and `INET_NTOA()`. Don't do a join, though, just delete addresses as they are used up.

Comment: Oh, and having a table of available addresses also solves the problem of your ranges being non-continuous.

Comment: @Beowulfenator thanks for suggestion. What do you mean by "just delete addresses"? Delete IP from table of available IP addresses after adding new one in table of used IP addresses?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just delete the address from the table of available addresses once you've used it. (And put it back if you free it up, by the way).

Comment: @Beowulfenator But if someone adds new  IP in table with used addresses out of the server, just by sql in db. I still need to check IP before adding it to table with used addresses

Comment: Don't let them!

Comment: @cmorrissey can you check my new solution?

Comment: @Beowulfenator can you check my new solution?

Comment: Your solution is highly inefficient. There is no real benefit to fetching the whole table from the DB and manipulating it in PHP. Performance will degrade as the amount of entries in your table increases. However, I doubt that this code will be used for large amounts of data, so it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I've found better solution without extra table in database

```
class Radreply extends ActiveRecord {

  const ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS = 'Framed-IP-Address';

  const IP_ADDRESS_MAX = '10.255.255.255';  // max value for IP 
  const IP_ADDRESS_MIN = '10.0.0.11';       // min value for IP

  public function getIntegerIP(){  // converts IP from string to integer format
      return ip2long($this->value);
  }

    public static function getFreeIPAddress(){
        $records = self::findAll(['attribute'=>self::ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT_IP_ADDRESS]); // gets all record which contain IP address
        $existIPs = ArrayHelper::getColumn($records,'integerIP'); // gets array of IP which is converted to integer by method getIntegerIP

        $intIpAddressMin = ip2long(self::IP_ADDRESS_MIN);     // gets min IP in integer format
        $endRange = empty($existIPs) ? $intIpAddressMin : max($existIPs);  // checks if at least one IP is used
        $availableIPs = range( $intIpAddressMin, $endRange + 2);   // generates array with available IP addresses (+2 because next address can be with last digit 0)
        $missingIPs = array_diff($availableIPs,$existIPs);  // removes all used IP

        foreach ($missingIPs as $value){
            $lastDigit = $value % 256;
            if ($lastDigit != 0){
                return long2ip($value);
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

In  my  opinion，you  can set strict  true .

my php  code  with **strict = false**

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                            

 $y="1800";
 $x = array();
 for($j=0;$j<50000;$j++){
        $x[]= "{$j}";
 }

 for($i=0;$i<30000;$i++){
    if(in_array($y,$x)){
            continue; 
     }
  }
```

time php test.php

```
real    0m4.418s
user    0m4.404s
 sys    0m0.012s
```

when strict  is **true**

```
for($i=0;$i<30000;$i++){
    if(in_array($y,$x ,true)){
              continue;
       }
 }
```

time php test.php

```
 real   0m1.548s
 user   0m1.540s
 sys    0m0.004s
```

what‘s more ,if you can get the used ip with ascending order . you can get the **o(m+n)**  time complexity,which m is the length of all ip you should try , n is the length of all ip in db with **merge algorithm** .

**if you can get the used ip with ascending order**

**in Pseudocode .**

```
tmpIp = minIp;
while(temIp <= maxIp){
         if( dbIsEmpty){
             break;
         }
            dbIp =getNextFromDb();

        while(temIp < dbIp){
         printf temIp ;
         temIp ++;
        }
        temIp ++;
 }
while(temIp <= maxIp){
    printf temIp ;
    temIp++;
}
```

here is my php code, where i repalce echo ip by  $count++;
**In this demo   there is about 80000 ip with type of long**

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                        
  function  mergeSort( $result){
    $minIp =  ip2long('10.0.0.11') ;
    $maxIp = ip2long('10.255.255.255');



    $count =0;
    $tmpIp = $minIp;
    while($temIp <= $maxIp){
         if( empty($result)){
        break ;
     }
     $tmp = array_pop($result);
     $dbIp =$tmp['ip'];

        while($temIp < $dbIp){
        // echo temIp ;
         // i repalce  it by count ++  , i don't want it 
        //full my teminal .
        $count ++;
         $temIp ++;
        }
        $temIp ++;   


    }
    while($temIp <= $maxIp){
        //echo  $temIp ; replace by $count++
        $count ++;
        $temIp++;
    }
    return $count -1;

}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "aaaaa";
$dbname = "IP";

$conn =  new PDO('mysql:host=' . $servername . ';dbname=' . $dbname , $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT , true);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from  ipTable  order by ip desc");
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
   $count  = mergeSort($result);
   echo $count ;
     ?>
```

it take about 10s ;
    time php test.php 
      184460881
     real   0m10.626s 
     user    0m10.416s 
     sys    0m0.168s

Comment: thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "merge algorithm"?

Comment: i  have  problem that you just  want  a  unused  ip  or   get   all  unused ip   once?

Comment: Only one unused IP adress

Comment: you  can  get  10000  unused  and  save to new  table  by merge algrithm. when you  want  a  unused  ip ，you  just get ip from this new  table,and add a row to the used (old )table. every time the new table is empty, use merge algorithm to get new 10000row

Comment: can you look at my new solution?